# How does Objective-C variable comparison work?

Tags: objective-c, comparison

I have some Objective C and I don't understand variable comparison operators:

```
if ([bmiView.text floatValue] < 18.50) {
    classification.text = @"Underweight";
    bmiImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"underweight.png"];
}
if ([bmiView.text floatValue] > 18.50 < 24.99) {
    classification.text = @"Healthy";
    bmiImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"healthy.png"];
}
if ([bmiView.text floatValue] > 25 < 29.99) {
    classification.text = @"Overweight";
    bmiImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overweight.png"];
}
if ([bmiView.text floatValue] > 30 < 39.99) {
    classification.text = @"Obese";
    bmiImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"obese.png"];
}
if ([bmiView.text floatValue] > 40) {
    classification.text = @"Very Obese";
    bmiImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"veryobese.png"];
}
```

Every time I run the application, the only classification that works properly is "Very Obese" when the user's BMI is over 40.00.  Any other BMI results in the classification below that, "Obese", which is supposed to be for BMIs between 30.00 and 39.99.  Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted.  The asker of this question is clearly making an attempt to understand the problem.

Comment: It's localized.  What person doing a google search for BMI classification in XCode would want to land on this site and read a post of someone learning that each variable comparisons must be spelled out.  It's this kind of stuff that will kill StackOverflow as a go-to site for getting what you need.  And the brilliant response from Joachim Isaksson is teaching learned helplessness to our budding minds.  Why find the answer yourself? Just post to SO.

Comment: @EricLeschinski I just needed to figure out why my code wasn't working properly. I didn't come to learn anything about BMI classification or my spelling on anything. I genuinely did not know that using > < didn't work as a way to state "greater than but less than". And I have been trying to find an answer that I obviously could not find. I came to SO because I knew people here could help me solve me problem. I learned something new and I'm glad that someone could help me.

Comment: It's like a child learning how to read by giving the parent the book and saying: "read this for me and gesture the idea to me".  The child isn't learning.  It's learning helplessness.  I have your best interests in mind, you aren't learning to problem solve.  Read this (http://sscce.org/) and do it, or you'll never be a programmer.

Comment: BTW, this isn't a question about xcode.  It is about objective-c (and possibly iOS)....  Changing your tag for you.  :)

Comment: @EricLeschinski +1 for letting us know about http://sscce.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ([bmiView.text floatValue] > 18.50 < 24.99) {
```

...does not do what you think it does. You need to do two comparisons instead;

```
if ([bmiView.text floatValue] > 18.50 && [bmiView.text floatValue] < 24.99) {
```

Note also that no case will hit for example if the float value is *exactly* 25.

It may be a good idea to just rewrite your code using `else` instead, so you can skip the check of the lower bound;

```
if ([bmiView.text floatValue] < 18.50) {
    classification.text = @"Underweight";
    bmiImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"underweight.png"];
}
else if ([bmiView.text floatValue] < 25.0) {
    classification.text = @"Healthy";
    bmiImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"healthy.png"];
}
...
```

A sidenote, what `[bmiView.text floatValue] > 18.50 < 24.99` does is to compare the floatvalue to `18.5`, generating 1 or 0 as a result depending on if it's true or false. It then goes on to compare if that 0/1 is less than 24.99, which is always true.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your comparison should be more like:

```
if ([bmiView.text floatValue] > 25 && [bmiView.text floatValue] < 29.99) {
    classification.text = @"Overweight";
    bmiImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"overweight.png"];
}
```